# Perl Search and Replace — issues is caused by "\"

Tags: perl, search, str-replace

I am parsing a text doc and replacing some text. Lines of text without the "\" seem to be found and replaced no issues.

By the way this is to be done in Perl

I have a string like below:

```
Path=S:\2014 March\Test Scenarios\load\2014 March
```

that contains "\" that slash is an issue. I am using a simple search and replace line of code

```
$nExit =~ s/$sMatchPattern/$sFullReplacementString/;
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you're trying to match a literal string, and therefore need to escape regex special characters.

You can use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or the escape codes `\Q ... \E` to do that:

```
$nExit = s/\Q$sMatchPattern/$sFullReplacementString/;
```

The above variable `$sMatchPattern` will be interpolated, but then any special characters will be escaped before the regex is compiled.  Therefore the value of `$sMatchPattern` will be treated like a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

Is this string inputed, or is it embedded in your program. You could do this to get rid of the backslash character:

```
my $path = "S:/2014 March/Test Scenarios/load/2014 March";
```

By the way, it's best not to have spaces in file and path names. They can be a bit problematic in certain situations. If you can't eliminate them, it's understandable.

Two things you should look at:

1. Use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) which can help *quote* special characters in strings and allow you to use them in substitutions. Even if you had backslashes in your strings, `quotemeta` will handle them.
2. You don't have to use `/` as separators in match and substitutions. Instead, you can substitute various other characters.

These are all the same:

```
$string =~ s/$regex/$replace/;
$string =~ s#$regex#$replace#;
$string =~ s|$regex|$replace|;
```

You can also use parentheses, square braces, or curly brackets:

```
$string =~ s($regex)($replace);
$string =~ s[$regex][$replace]; # Not really recommended because `[...]` is a common regex
$string =~ s{$regex}{$replace};
```

The advantage of these as regular expression quote-like characters is that they must be balanced, so if I had this:

```
my $string  = "I have (parentheses) in my string";
my $regex   = "(parentheses}";
my $replace = "{curly braces}";

$string = s($regex)($replace);
print "$string\n";   # Still works. This will be "I have {curly braces} in my string"
```

Even if my string contains these types of characters, as long as they're balanced, everything will still work.

For yours:

```
my $Path = 'S:\2014 March\Test Scenarios\load\2014 March';
$nExit = quotemeta $string;  #Quotes all meta characters...
$nExit =~ s($sMatchPattern)($sFullReplacementString);
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a \ in your replacement string or match string dont forget to put another backslash in front of the backslash you want, as its an operator...

```
$sFullReplacementString = "\\";
```

That would turn the string into a single \